# Kindle Fire SDK not found in Eclipse Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, kindle-fire

I was going through a walk through for installing Kindle Fire's SDK in Eclipse. 
But in the Android SDK manager, kindle Fire isnt listed anywhere.
I have updated the IDE, so i still dont know why its not there.

any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kindle Fire is not officially supported by Google. However, you can connect the Fire to your computer and develop on it using the 2.3 SDK. You won't be able to create an emulator for it though.

Update: never mind apparently they now provide an "add on" SDK. Check [this page](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/emulator-guide.html?ref_=pe_132830_25708000) out.

Comment: dmon https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/devportal2/content/sdk/images/SDKManWindow.png

Comment: though I added Add-on Site URL, but I am not able to see the SDK platform for Kindle such as Kindle Fire HD 7"etc. Any clue??

Comment: I am also set up kindle development environment and  In the Add Add-on Site URL dialog box, I enter the following URL:
http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml but kindle system image options is not displays only device defination and usb driver show. How should I configure this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: I added the Add-On Site, but the only add-on that shows up is the USB driver. I don't see any system images for Kindle Fire.

Comment: it's been discontinued, I don't know how to work around it though

Answer (score 1):

The Kindle Fire is not available on [Google add-on site](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/).

**But you can download the SDK via the add-on link as :**

**http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml**

For more info please follow :

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/setup.html

Comment: @AnujSharma Link is not eclipse addon. It is a SDK addon , you need to go to Android SDK Manager window, on the Tools menu, click Manage Add-on Sites. Click the User Defined Sites tab, and then click New. 
Note: In Mac OS X, when the Android SDK Manager window is open, the Tools menu appears in the parent Eclipse window instead of the Android SDK Manager window.
In the Add Add-on Site URL dialog box, enter the following URL: 
http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml

Comment: though I added Add-on Site URL, but I am not able to see the SDK platform for Kindle such as Kindle Fire HD 7"etc. Any clue??

Comment: @Virag make sure if you have download the updates from the add-on.

Comment: @ArpitGarg I have added the add-ons but still after adding the add-on link into Manage Add-ons Site,  can not able to see any kindle related stuff for downloading..

Answer (score 1):

There are simple steps to be followed.

1. In eclipse go to **Windows --> Android SDK** Manager click to open it.
2. Then it will open the sdk manager then on the top two menus are listed one for 
   **Packages** and other for **Tools**.
3. Then open the tools menu click **Manage Add-on Sites**. Click the User Defined Sites tab, and then click New.
4. In the **Add Add-on Site URL** dialog box, enter the following URL: http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml Click OK, and then click Close.Wait for the Android SDK Manager to refresh.
5. In the Android SDK Manager window, select the latest revision of each of the listed packages. which shows the all the versions of the kindle fire to install ... Choose it. For example

   **Android 4.0.3 API 15:**

   SDK Platform

   **ARM EABI v7a System Image** (emulator prerequisite for ARM system images)

   **Intel x86 Atom System Image** (emulator prerequisite for x86 system images)

   **Kindle Fire (2nd Generation)** (ARM and x86 system images for emulator)

   **Kindle Fire HD 7"** (ARM and x86 system images for emulator)

   **Kindle Fire HD 8.9** (ARM and x86 system images for emulator)

   Install all of this then close the Android Sdk Manager and then restart eclipse .

   The following link explains it more clearer [here](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/setup.html).

Comment: though I added Add-on Site URL, but I am not able to see the SDK platform for Kindle such as Kindle Fire HD 7"etc. Any clue??

Answer (score 1):

All change at Amazon. At the time of writing this is the Kindle SDK install guide:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment

And in particular note that the URL used to get the Fire SDK AddOn installed via the SDK Tools is now:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/addon.xml

Answer (score 0):

Amazon removed the emulator support for eclipse please check the following thread for more information [Click here](http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=479)

You can test few api of fire phone by following [This](http://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/using-the-api-simulator-tool)